# Set the Drawable icon of other app to the notification builder

Tags: android, image, notifications, android-notification-bar

I am working on application, In that application I am getting other application info. And the info show on the notification builder.
I am getting the other application icon, and want to show on the notification. But the getting info contain drawable image.

So, how can I show the draw able image on the notification.
Here is my sample of code.

```
 String packageName=appSetting.getHeavyDrainingAppName();

 ApplicationInfo app = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

 int iconId = ......????



 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                    .setSmallIcon(iconId)
                                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.heavy_drain_text))
                                    .setContentText("Tap to stop")
                                    .setOngoing(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is some points about this question:

1st :

You can set the LargeIcon from a Drawable (instead of Resource id), like the following

```
Drawable icon = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap();

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                            .setContentTitle("hahah")
                            .setContentText("Tap to stop")
                            .setOngoing(true);
```

2nd :

If you need to set a SmallIcon in API below 23, you will need to set a resource id like `R.drawable.your_resource`.
The NotificationCompat.Builder does not allow you to use Drawable`s or Bitmaps in`setSmallIcon()`.

3rd :

fortunately , the support has been expanded to `Icon` type on `setSmallIcon()` in version 23+, using the Notification.Builder, like following :

```
Drawable icon = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap();

            Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                    new Notification.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap))
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                            .setContentTitle("hahah")
                            .setContentText("Tap to stop")
                            .setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: Which part have you tried? Because i wrote that you CAN`T use setSmallIcon with Drawable or Bitmap, in pré 23 version.

Comment: i am trying first part according to my requirment.

Comment: i am getting draw able image, not id of the image. so i use the first part.

Comment: you are getting the drawable correctly, i mean, you tried this drawable in a random image to see if the problem is in it ?

Comment: i am use this logic in services

Comment: it gives you any crash ?

Comment: Not i not give any crash. notification not appear in notification bar.

Comment: NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, mBuilder.build());

Comment: do you did this /\ ?

Comment: if i use setSmallIcon(R.id.my_icon) the notification appear. but when i use setLargeIcon(bitmap) the notification not appear.

Comment: Can you have a look in your logcat, if there`s a Error or Warn about this?

Comment: In log cat there is no any Error or warn. the last line of log cat is
07-29 23:55:00.786 26584-26584/com.example.sohaibraza.projectfirst D/asset: AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!

Comment: you`ll need to do this call to Drawable icon = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
in a activity and set the Drawable to a imageview to see if the Drawable is the problem... after that we keep trying

Comment: there is no problem in draw able. it get the image, but not set to the notification.

Comment: yes solve the problem. by set the .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) .setLargeIcon(bitmap) both at a time

Comment: Thank you for your struggle